# Is there any method to move the map's camera when we draw polygon using "react-google-maps/api"'s Drawing Manager component?

Tags: react-google-maps-api

I can't move the map's camera when I'm drawing polygon using DrawingManager component when it touches the corners of the map.

[Here, we can see the map doesn't move its camera along with mouse event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awuQv.png)

I am tried using onOverlayComplete & onPolygonComplete methods from DrawingManager. Both are works after we drew the polygon. I need to capture event when we draw the Polygon using mouse event.
How to achieve this?